# if Div is selected - hasClass - trigger some events, if not - trigger other events. Can this be achieved as independent function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class, if-statement

I need to trigger different events with `if` `else if` `else`, depending on whether an element of a certain class is selected or not. When I try this, not only that it doesn't work, it also blocks other functions:

http://jsfiddle.net/nur6qphr/2/

```
if ( $('.a').hasClass('selected') ) {
    $('.bg').css({'border':'solid 1px red'}); //change other div's css
} else if ( $('.b').hasClass('selected') ) {
    $('.bg').css({'border':'solid 1px green'}); //change other div's css
} else {
    $('.bg').css({'border':'solid 1px'});
};
```

This is btw just simplified illustration of the problem, I don't need actual css change, so I don't need a pure css solution for this particular fiddle.

**edit:** removed () next to else, so it doesn't block other f anymore, but it still doesn't work...

Is there any way to make `if` functional without wrapping it inside the click function?

**edit2**: I guess not in a simple and rational way.

Comment: remove the ()-brackets after else

Comment: done, so it doesn't block other f but still doesn't change the border. is there any way to make `if` functional without wrapping it inside the click f?

Comment: you should set classes not styles, styles are from 1998 (they don't separate style from logic, don't allow for normal cascading priority, don't allow people to modify styles without modifying code etc)

Comment: thanks for the advice. however, it didn't helped in this case. I tried to replace `.css` with `.addClass` and it's still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things,

1) You have incorrect syntax for else.

2) You need to wrap the code in click event for code to work on click.

**Use:**

```
$('.tiles').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('selected');
 if ( $('.a').hasClass('selected') ) {
 $('.bg').css({'border':'solid 1px red'});
 } else if ( $('.b').hasClass('selected') ) {
 $('.bg').css({'border':'solid 1px green'});
 } else{
 $('.bg').css({'border':'solid 1px'});
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/manantwar/f9Ldmypb/)**

Comment: 1) done 2) how can this be functional without wrapping?

Comment: @astx123: i think it is better if you put the code in click event. otherwise you may need to use `setInterval()`  or change in dom event listener which would be unnecessary.

Comment: hmm... I thought that independent `if` would be better, because I need this mainly for keyboard. but if I have too, I guess I should improvise.

Comment: @astx123: yes. that is best approach to consider while achieving functionality.